# How to "npm start" an html file with css stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm new to coding and (obviously) getting Qs in stack overflow allows me to interact more with other developers.

I code on VS Code and I know there is a "live server" extension in order to do exactly what I need my code to do. BUT, up until the last time I tried "npm start" for another code it was working and now I'm starting a simple html/css/js code it just says:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\.\..\...\....\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\.\..\...\....\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I've done a bit of research and I know i need to either run `npm install` or `npm init`.

However my `npm install` won't fix the issue, and the `npm init` does create the `package.json` file, **BUT** won't fix the issue.

Also, after running `npm init`, it says I don't have the "start" script, and even after I set up the script, it won't work.

I've already:

1. Deleted all .json files and ran npm install.
2. ran npm init and added the "start" script.
3. rebooted my pc.
4. uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code.
5. done the whole code again on another computer.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: first of all `npm start` works when you have installed node.js and launched for example `lite-server`, but you must have also `package.json` file to configure and set in there `"start": "lite-server"` but, on **live-server** you can just right click in HTML file and click "Open with Live-server", it doesn't need any JSON file configuration

Comment: Hello, my issue was going around the package.json file, that even though I had, it didn't work whatever way possible.
As I was working on a React app, obviously I needed to config package.json. I even tried to do something similar to what you said, but, instead of "lite-server", I just added npm start. or live-server.

I'll try lite-server this time and I'll update you on it.

Comment: to install lite-server with npm, run this command `npm install --save-dev lite-server`  and dont forget to include in your package.json scripts `"start": "lite-server"` and then run `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

First off let me say you do not need npm or live server to view a simple HTML, CSS and JS project.  You can just open the HTML file using your web browser.  Assuming you know that let me cover what the npm commands are doing because it confused me at first.

- npm init sets up a new or existing package. (creates package.json)
- npm install will install all the required packages for your current project (dependencies from package.json)

The start command in your package.json is just the bit of code that gets run when you actually type npm start.  Basically what it all comes down to is you do not need to run any sort of start command unless your application needs to run on a server which a simple HTML CSS and JS does not.

Live Server is similar to what happens when you run the start command it is just an extension offered through VSCode.  Another useful extension I use is "Open in default browser" for my basic HTML CSS and JS files.

Comment: Thanks man! - I knew already we could just run the file on the browser, but mine wasn't accepting. - I honestly think the way I setup my pc doesn't help me overall on these codes. I've had plenty of trouble over react/node projects due to this and Powershell. which is why I'm sticking to html/css. thanks again.